# Generating a warning when I/O size limit is exceeded

Tags: powershell

A function is doing IO operation . If the IO reaches a size more than warning limit storage array will send the event to host. The same function will fetch the event.

I have used the verb-noun pattern and the name of the function is as below.

> `"Get-SoftAlertAfterRunIO"`

It is not making sense as it is not only getting, it is also generating.

Another name I can use is:

> `Generate-SoftAlert`

But it is not an approved verb. What could be the equivalent verb for generate?

Or is there any good name to reflect the behavior of this code.

The full code is given below

```
    function Generate-SoftAlert  {
    param
    (        
        $VolumeObject,
        $Size
    )  

    $Path = $VolumeObject.Path
    $IOTimeStamp = StartIO -Path $Path -LimitSizeInGB $Size 

    $IOStarttimeInArray = $IOTimeStamp.IOStarttimeInArray
    $IOStarttimeInHost = $IOTimeStamp.IOStartTimeInHost

    $IOEndtimeInArray = $IOTimeStamp.IOEndtimeInArray
    $IOEndtimeInHost = $IOTimeStamp.IOendTimeInHost

    $VolumeName = $VolumeObject.Name
    $IsSoftAlertInArray= Test-SoftAlertInArray -VolumeName $VolumeName -FromTimeStamp $IOStarttimeInArray -ToTimestamp $IOEndtimeInArray

    $DiskNumber = $VolumeObject.DiskNumber
    $SoftAlert = Get-SoftAlertInHost -After $IOStarttimeInHost -Before $IOEndtimeInHost -DiskNumber $DiskNumber
    $IsSoftAlert = ($SoftAlert -ne $null)

    $Message = $SoftAlert.Message
    $IsLogSense = $false
    If($IsSoftAlert -eq $true)
    {
        $IsLogSense = Test-LogSenseMessage -LogMessage $Message -DiskNumber $DiskNumber -thresholdInGb $WarningLimit   
    }

    return [pscustomobject]@{
        SoftAlert = $IsSoftAlert        
        LogSense = $IsLogSense
        SoftAlertInArray = $IsSoftAlertInArray
    }
}
```

Comment: `A function is doing IO operation and once the IO reaches a given size it will trigger the event and the function will fetch it.` What is "it" in "**it** will trigger the event"? What is "it" in "the function will fetch **it**"?

Comment: @Flater I have updated the question

Comment: Are you ok with others reviewing more than just your question about naming - the rest of the code? Would you be ok if people _don't_ mention changing the function's name?

Comment: Might be a good idea to take a look at the [help/on-topic] to get an idea of what to expect here.

Answer (score 2):

Apply [Approved Verbs for Windows PowerShell Commands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714428(v=vs.85).aspx) article from [Windows PowerShell Cmdlet Concepts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878268(v=vs.85).aspx), use **`New-SoftAlert`**:

> ### Common Verbs
>
> Windows PowerShell uses the [VerbsCommon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.verbscommon(v=vs.85).aspx) enumeration class to
>   define generic actions that can apply to almost any cmdlet…
>
> <sub>Verb (alias):</sub> **New** (`n`)
>
> <sub>Action:</sub> Creates a resource. (The `Set` verb can also be used when creating a resource that includes data, such as the `Set-Variable`
>   cmdlet.)
>
> <sub>Comments:</sub> For this action, *do not use* verbs such as Create, *Generate*, Build, Make, or Allocate.